# Is there a built-in function to read from set reader?

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

Nashorn allows us to write to the writer which the engine uses via print() function. Is there a way to read from the reader using a built-in function?
Example:

```
Socket input=new Socket("stackoverflow.com", 1234);  
Socket output=new Socket("stackoverflow.com", 4321);  
engine.getContext().setWriter(new InputStreamReader(input.getInputStream())); //Changing to Socket input's reader from default one, which should be System.in.  
engine.getContext().setWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())); //Changing from System.out to Socket output's output stream.
```

In that case, if I use print("hello"), Socket output will receive the message. But how can I read what Socket input sends?

Comment: I can guess from the tags, but you should specify what `engine` is.

Comment: @chrylis Done. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: You can read input from a file as in: Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("...myfiles/input.in"); this will read from Input file. Then you can process the input stream, line by line.

Answer (score 0):

When you use setReader and setWriter on the ScriptContext, you are setting the default input and output streams for the Javascript context.  So, what you are doing here is configuring Javascript to read from and write to socket streams.

How those streams are made available to the Javascript code will depend on the JS environment / libraries you are using.  However, with Node.js, you can see them as `process.stdin` and `process.stdout`.

FWIW, access to stdin / stdout is not supported in the standard ECMAScript libraries.

Comment: I'm using Nashorn script engine inside a Java application. I could always use a Java object to get input, but then what's the purpose of having or being able to set a reader if there is no way to use it? What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes, you could it that way.  But then you wouldn't need to do the `setReader` and `setWriter` calls.  Also, I never said that that was no way to use the reader set by `setReader`.  What I said was that there was no *standard* way to do it.  The point is that the Java "script engine" APIs are offering functionality that is in advance of what the current ECMAScript spec requires or supports.